# setTimeout working with async-await keywords but don't know how it works

Tags: ecmascript-6, async-await, settimeout

I'm programming with javascript and I stumbled on this code I wonder how and why the code below works:

```
var test = async () => {
  console.log("before");
  await setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("after");
  }, 1000);

};
test();
```

It log's this:

1. "before"
2. "after"

This is a sample code, but my question is how is this working?
setTimeout() doesn't return a Promise (I think) so the async/await pair should not work or is something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it *doesn't* work:

```
async function test() {
  console.log("before");
  await setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("callback");
  }, 1000);
  console.log("after");
}
test();
```

You will receive `before` - `after` - `callback`. The `await` doesn't stop anything, because - as you recognised - `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise. It waits for `undefined` and continues with the next statement. Your example just was lacking that next statement, so you couldn't see a difference. Here's a working example:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}
async function test() {
  console.log("before");
  await delay(1000);
  console.log("after");
}
test();
```

Comment: `resolve => setTimeout(t)`, maybe? Or am I missing something too?

Answer (score -2):

As per [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

> If the value of the *expression* following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.

So, the `await setTimeout` expression is converted to a resolved Promise.

Comment: Read OP's question please

Comment: Responding to "setTimeout() doesn't return a Promise (I think) so the async/wait pair should not work or is something that I'm missing?"

Comment: I think the real question is : `Is redux-thunk (for example) really needed for async calls or is this a feature of ES6 that is doing some magic?`

Comment: Besides, the question title : `React and Redux with an async/await call in dispatch method without any middleware working` does not mention anything about settimeout working with async/await

Comment: That's fair, though I thought the question of _magic_ was worth addressing.

Comment: You were right after all, OP edited it's question and changed the title. Still, await with setTimeout won't work, (well it will work, but with an immediate resolution no matter the timeout)

Comment: Agreed it won't await for the setTimeout to fire, but it will work as per the definition of using `await` in front of an expression that does not return a promise.